# unresolved attribute reference 'replace' for class 'int' on the replace function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why the replace got **unresolved attribute reference 'replace' for class 'int'**  error. And then when the money reach more than 1000, I got value error, even though I tried to handle it with exception by removing comma from the string :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\Day48_selenium_cookie_clicker\main.py", line 37, in <module>
    money = int(cookies_owned.text)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,012'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\Day48_selenium_cookie_clicker\main.py", line 50, in <module>
    money = int(cookies_owned.text)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,012'
```

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from timeit import default_timer as timer

chrome_driver_path = "C:\Development\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("http://orteil.dashnet.org/experiments/cookie/")

timeout = 30  # [seconds]

time_check = time.time() + 5

ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')  # find all ids within a webpage
ids_list = [i.get_attribute('id') for i in ids]
items_for_sale_ids = [i for i in ids_list if i[0] == "b" and i[1] == "u" and i[2] == "y"][:8]

items_data = [i.text.split("\n") for i in driver.find_elements_by_id("store")][0]
items_for_sale = [items_data[i].split(" - ") for i in range(len(items_data)) if i % 2 == 0]
price = [int(y[1].replace(",", "")) for y in items_for_sale]
items_pricelist = list(zip(items_for_sale_ids, price))
items_pricelist_dict = {i[1]: i[0] for i in items_pricelist}
start = timer()

cookie = driver.find_element_by_id("cookie")

while True:
    cookie.click()
    if time.time() > time_check:
        # print("hello")
        cookies_owned = driver.find_element_by_id("money")
        try:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text)
            affordable_upgrades = {}
            for cost, id in items_pricelist_dict.items():
                if money > cost:
                    affordable_upgrades[cost] = id

            max_upgrade = max(affordable_upgrades)
            print(max_upgrade)
            to_purchase_id = affordable_upgrades[max_upgrade]
            to_buy = driver.find_element_by_id((to_purchase_id))
            to_buy.click()
            time_check = time.time() + 5
        except ValueError:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text)
            formatted_money = money.replace(",", "")
            affordable_upgrades = {}
            for cost, id in items_pricelist_dict.items():
                if formatted_money > cost:
                    affordable_upgrades[cost] = id

            max_upgrade = max(affordable_upgrades)
            print(max_upgrade)
            to_purchase_id = affordable_upgrades[max_upgrade]
            to_buy = driver.find_element_by_id((to_purchase_id))
            to_buy.click()
            time_check = time.time() + 5
```

Comment: Integer can't parse the string with the comma in there. If you are in a locale where comma is the decimal separator, use `float()`.

Comment: Looks like you try to remove the comma, but in the wrong place. Remove the comma _before_ converting to int: `money = int(cookies_owned.text.replace(",", ""))`

Comment: ...As you are already doing properly with `int(y[1].replace(",", ""))` some lines before that...

Comment: thank you guys, now I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I got value error, even though I tried to handle it with exception by removing comma from the string :

```py
        try:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text)
            ...
        except ValueError:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text)
            ...
```

Yes, you handle Exception and after that raise same error again ;)

Correct code is:

```py
        try:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text)
            ...
        except ValueError:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text.replace(",", ""))
            ...
```

Or simpler:

```py
        try:
            money = int(cookies_owned.text.replace(",", ""))
            ...
        except ...
```

Here is no problem to replace `,` anytime. You don't need to wait for exception. `replace(",", "")` will be correct for any number (`1`, `100`, `1,000`, `1,000,000`, ...)

Answer (score 0):

see below.
(the problem is the `,` in value. once we remove it - it works)

```
value = '1,012'
try:
  int_value = int(value)
except ValueError:
  print('failed - lets try again..')
int_value = int(value.replace(',',''))
print(int_value)
```

output

```
failed - lets try again..
1012
```

Comment: I see, thank you :)

Comment: @Stephen Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work: (see comments inserted in the code)

```py
money = int(cookies_owned.text)          # money is now an int
formatted_money = money.replace(",", "") # ... but you treat it as a string
```